# Which is the shortest way to integrate something like $\int\left(\frac{dv}{g-\frac{k}{m} v^2}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I know that it can be integrated by trigonometrical substitution but I wonder if there is a shortest or easiest way

$\int\left(\dfrac{dv}{g-\frac{k}{m} v^2}\right)$, where $g, k , m$ are positive constant values.

Comment: Partial fractions looks easiest (at least if $k,m,g$ are positive constants).

Comment: Arctan function or log function (partial fraction). It depends on the sign of the constants.

Comment: Please avoid displayed equations and display-like formatting in titles/subject lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\frac{gm}{k}>0$, substitute $v=\sqrt{\frac {gm}k}\sin\theta\implies dv=\sqrt{\frac {gm}k}\cos\theta d\theta$   $$\int\dfrac{dv}{g-\frac{k}{m} v^2}=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac {gm}k}\cos\theta d\theta}{g-\frac{k}{m} \left(\sqrt{\frac {gm}k}\sin\theta\right)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac {gm}k}\int\dfrac{\cos\theta d\theta}{g\cos^2\theta}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac {m}{gk}}\int\sec\theta\ d\theta$$

$$=\sqrt{\frac {m}{gk}}\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C$$

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int\dfrac{dv}{g-\frac{k}{m} v^2}=\dfrac 1 g\int\dfrac{dv}{1-\frac{k}{gm} v^2}$$

Now use arctan function for $\frac{k}{gm}<0$ ( change of variable). Otherwise use fraction decomposition and the log function.

Comment: Or for $k/gm>0$ you could use $v=\sqrt{\frac{gm}{k}}\sin t$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes you're right.